# SWIFT: CoreLocation - Ranging Beacons using CLBeaconIdentityConstraint does not range multiple beacons

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon, geofencing

So, we have encountered a problem, developing in Swift for iOS 13. When we use the newer method for ranging beacons "startRangingBeacons(satisfying: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint )" it will only range the most recently added beacon, so if there are more than one beacon, we have a problem. When we use the older method, "startRangingBeacons(in: region)," now deprecated but still functional in iOS 13, the app works as expected.

Details (using the newer method with "constraints"):

1. App StartsMonitoring 2 Beacon regions
2. Starts Ranging Beacons if the user enters a BeaconRegion
3. Turn on Beacon1, the app starts ranging Beacon1
4. Turn on Beacon2, the app starts ranging Beacon2, but does not range beacon1. (NOTE - Both beacons regions overlap, and the older method can handle this)

When ranged beacons with startRangingBeacons(in: region), the app was able to range both beacons.

When the latest ranged beacon is turned off, didRangeBeacons event is triggered with empty CLBeacon list, which should still have the other beacon in, but it does not.

Here is the code that does not work:

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRange beacons: [CLBeacon], satisfying beaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint) {

     for beacon in beacons {
         if [.near, .immediate].contains(beacon.proximity){
             if let index = beaconsInProximity.firstIndex(of: beacon) {
                 beaconsInProximity.remove(at: index)
             }
             beaconsInProximity.append(beacon)
             if beaconsInProximity.count > 1 { beaconsInProximity = beaconsInProximity.sorted(by: {$0.accuracy < $1.accuracy})}
             if nearestBeacon == nil || !nearestBeacon!.isEqual(beaconsInProximity[0]) {
                 if(nearestBeacon != nil) {
                     notifyUser(isExiting: true, isBeacon = true)
                 }
                 nearestBeacon = beaconsInProximity[0]
                 displayOrSendNotification()
             }

         } else if let index = beaconsInProximity.firstIndex(of: beacon){
             if(beaconsInProximity.count > 1) {
                 beaconsInProximity.remove(at: index)
                 if nearestBeacon != nil && nearestBeacon!.isEqual(beacon) {
                     notifyUser(isExiting: true, isBeacon = true)
                     nearestBeacon = beaconsInProximity.count > 0 ? beaconsInProximity[0] : nil
                     displayOrSendNotification()
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that works:

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                     didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon],
                     in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    print("Did range beacons")

    for beacon in beacons {
        if [.near, .immediate].contains(beacon.proximity){
            if let index = beaconsInProximity.firstIndex(of: beacon) {
                beaconsInProximity.remove(at: index)
            }
            beaconsInProximity.append(beacon)
            if beaconsInProximity.count > 1 { beaconsInProximity = beaconsInProximity.sorted(by: {$0.accuracy < $1.accuracy})}
            if nearestBeacon == nil || !nearestBeacon!.isEqual(beaconsInProximity[0]) {
                if(nearestBeacon != nil) {
                    displayOrSendNotification(isExiting: true, isBeacon: true)
                }
                nearestBeacon = beaconsInProximity[0]
                displayOrSendNotification(isExiting: false, isBeacon: true)
            }

        } else if let index = beaconsInProximity.firstIndex(of: beacon){
            if(beaconsInProximity.count > 1) {
                beaconsInProximity.remove(at: index)
                if nearestBeacon != nil && nearestBeacon!.isEqual(beacon) {
                    nearestBeacon = beaconsInProximity.count > 0 ? beaconsInProximity[0] : nil
                    displayOrSendNotification(isExiting: false, isBeacon: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Creating beacons to monitor:

```swift
var regionsToMonitor = [
        BeaconData(uuid: UUID(uuidString: "82eee62a-b285-44dc-88e9-531188ee72e7")!, major: 0, minor: 1, name: "Dime Team", description: "Awesome Innovations", image: "beacon-icon"),
        BeaconData(uuid: UUID(uuidString: "c2db97d9-6e80-44a2-82f5-3987065ba4ea")!, major: 7, minor: 11, name: "Data Team", description: "Busy Team", image: "beacon-icon")]
```

BeaconData Definition

```
struct BeaconData: RegionData{

    let uuid: UUID
    let major: NSNumber
    let minor: NSNumber
    let beaconRegion: CLBeaconRegion
    let name: String
    let detail: String
    let image: String

    init(uuid:  UUID, major: NSNumber, minor: NSNumber, name: String, description: String, image: String) {
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.major = major
        self.minor = minor
        self.beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(beaconIdentityConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: uuid), identifier: name)
        self.name = name
        self.detail = description
        self.image = image
    }
    init(uuid:  UUID, major: NSNumber, minor: NSNumber, beaconRegion: CLBeaconRegion, name: String, description: String, image: String) {
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.major = major
        self.minor = minor
        self.beaconRegion = beaconRegion
        self.name = name
        self.detail = description
        self.image = image
    }

    func contains(region: CLRegion) -> Bool {
        return self.beaconRegion == region
    }
}
```

Here is the code to start ranging. Commented call on the bottom works as desired. Uncommented call above that is the wonky one. W create the constraint inline in the call, just the UUID. It works for one beacon, but as soon as we add a second (with different UUID as noted above) it only ranges the most recent.

```swift
        for region in beaconRegionsToRange {
            print("Start Ranging \(region.uuid)")
            locationManager.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: region.uuid))
            //locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
        }
```

How do we get it to range all beacons with the newer "satisfyingConstraints" method?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant code; in particular how you start ranging a beacon once you get the region entry.

Comment: Done, thanks @PaulW11

Comment: Please show your code look like that constructs a CLBeaconIdentityConstraint that causes the problem you describe.  Please also show the CLRegion definition you use to start ranging with the deprecated method such that it does work. Finally, please tell us the specific identifiers of the two beacons that cause the issue you describe.

Comment: I'm adding some code now, I apologize for the delay, WFH shenanigans and all... I'm fairly new at asking questions here, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Its looking to me like a bug; As soon as I start ranging for a second `CLBeaconIdentityConstraint`, I stop receiving range updates for the beacons that match the first `CLBeaconIdentityConstraint`, even though `rangedBeaconConstraints` shows both the first and second constraints.

Comment: That was our thought, too, @Paulw11, but we thought maybe we were overlooking something.

Comment: So, we think this is a bug, we posted it to the apple developer forum, so far no response. Thanks to all who responded and who pushed for e to post additional details.

Comment: @CaptainChaos, Can you please post a link to the bug report?

Comment: My pair wrote it up and submitted it, I'll get it from her.

Comment: @davidgyoung here is the link to the question in the developer forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/130360