# startRangingBeaconsSatisfyingConstraint multiple beacons

Tags: ios, uuid, ibeacon, locationmanager

When i use `startRangingBeaconsInRegion` with different regions `didRangeBeacons inRegion` can determine all the beacons that i set, but when i am doing the same with `startRangingBeaconsSatisfyingConstraint` `didRangeBeacons satisfyingConstraint` can determine only the last one. Is it the apple bug?

`startRangingBeaconsInRegion`

```
for (NSString *uuidString in uuidsString) {
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];

    CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithUUID:uuid identifier:uuidString];
    [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
}
```

`startRangingBeaconsSatisfyingConstraint`

```
for (NSString *uuidString in uuidsString) {
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];        

    CLBeaconIdentityConstraint *beaconIdentityConstraint = [[CLBeaconIdentityConstraint alloc] initWithUUID:uuid];
    [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsSatisfyingConstraint:beaconIdentityConstraint];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This appears to be a recently introduced bug** in CoreLocation with the new `startRangingBeaconsSatisfyingConstraint` API.

The workaround for now is to use the deprecated `startRangingBeaconsInRegion` API.

See related post here:

[SWIFT: CoreLocation - Ranging Beacons using CLBeaconIdentityConstraint does not range multiple beacons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729509/swift-corelocation-ranging-beacons-using-clbeaconidentityconstraint-does-not)

And the Apple forum post reporting the bug:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/130360

Comment: thanks! spent a few hours trying to find a problem in my code.