# Of my iBeacon's three minors, I am only able to range one of them. How can I range all three?

Tags: ibeacon

My iBeacon is set up to select between three minor values using a switch.  The switch sets the value of the iBeacon minor.  So only one minor is transmitting at any given time.  But I can only reliably range the iBeacon with the "00" minor.  I would like to range any one of the three, depending on where the selection switch is set.

Here is my code:

```
class LifeGardViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
var detectorID:UInt16? = 10//major for all three minors
var safeBeaconRegion: CLBeaconRegion?
var lowBatteryBeaconRegion: CLBeaconRegion?
var gasolineVaporBeaconRegion: CLBeaconRegion?
var safeBeaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint?
var lowBatteryBeaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint?
var gasolineVaporBeaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint?
var lifeGardBeaconUUID = UUID(uuidString: "6B4BCFCE-174E-4BAC-A814-092E77F6B700")!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.delegate = self
    locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}

func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
    
    switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        
        if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self){
            if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable(){
                
                buildBeaconRegionsAndConstraints()
                
            } else {
                
                //device is not compaitble, uninstall app
            }
        }
        
    case .notDetermined, .denied, .restricted:
        break
        
    default:
        break
    }
}

func buildBeaconRegionsAndConstraints() {
    
    safeBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(uuid: lifeGardBeaconUUID, major: detectorID!, minor: 00, identifier: "Life-Gard Safe Beacon")
    safeBeaconConstraint = CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: lifeGardBeaconUUID, major: detectorID!, minor: 00)
    
    lowBatteryBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(uuid: lifeGardBeaconUUID, major: detectorID!, minor: 01, identifier: "Life-Gard Low Battery Beacon")
    lowBatteryBeaconConstraint = CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: lifeGardBeaconUUID, major: detectorID!, minor: 01)
    
    gasolineVaporBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(uuid: lifeGardBeaconUUID, major: detectorID!, minor: 02, identifier: "Life-Gard Gasoline Vapor Beacon")
    gasolineVaporBeaconConstraint = CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: lifeGardBeaconUUID, major: detectorID!, minor: 02)
    
    
    startMonitoring()
}

func startMonitoring(){
    
    locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: safeBeaconRegion!)
    locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: lowBatteryBeaconRegion!)
    locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: gasolineVaporBeaconRegion!)
    
    startRanging()
}

func startRanging(){
    
    locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: safeBeaconConstraint!)
    locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: lowBatteryBeaconConstraint!)
    locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: gasolineVaporBeaconConstraint!)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRange beacons: [CLBeacon], satisfying beaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint) {
    
        print(beacons)
}
}
```

Even if I comment out the lines to construct the beacon region and identity constraint for minor "00" neither of the other two minors gets ranged. This is true even if I remove the app from my phone first.

Looking forward to any ideas to try.

`

Answer (score 1):

The code shown in the question is correct.  If you run that code and a beacon is advertising `6B4BCFCE-174E-4BAC-A814-092E77F6B700 10 1` or `6B4BCFCE-174E-4BAC-A814-092E77F6B700 10 2` then iOS is supposed to give a callback to `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRange beacons: [CLBeacon], satisfying beaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint)` once per second with a count of the detected beacons.  If there is no detection of that beacon, the count should be zero.

Two possibilities:

1. Your device is not advertising the beacon identifier you think it is.  The easiest way to troubleshoot this is to get a second phone and use a beacon detector/transmitter app like my [Beacon Scope for iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/beacon-scope/id1315448039?platform=iphone), or [for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner&hl=en_US&gl=US&showAllReviews=true).
2. Your iPhone is misbehaving somehow.  There were [isolated reports that some iOS 13 devices failed to range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729509/swift-corelocation-ranging-beacons-using-clbeaconidentityconstraint-does-not) multiple `CLBeaconIdentityConstraint` instances, and using the deprecated `startRangingBeacons(region: CLBeaconRegion)` method resolved the issue. If you might try this deprecated method to see if it makes any difference.  If you do so, be sure to change your delegate method to the equivalent deprecated version.

Comment: David, thanks for confirming that my code is correct.  I checked out both of your suggestions.  1) The beacon is advertising the proper minors as designed.  2) The deprecated startRanging and delegate methods give the same result--only the 00 minor is detected.  Mixing new and deprecated methods didn't help either.  I will let you know if I ever figure it out.  Thanks again for your suggestions.

Comment: This is unexpected.  Three other things you might try: (1) check to see if you get callbacks to the `didDetermineState` callback for region entry/exit events for the other two beacons.     (2) See if you get a callback to `func locationManager(CLLocationManager, didFailRangingFor: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint, error: Error)` (3) Try changing your first identity constraint to leave the minor nil, then see if you get callbacks for the other two beacons.  The third option is how I always build similar apps, and because I do it that way, I may not realize when multiple constraints sometimes fail.

Comment: David thanks again for the tips.  I tried them.  No error callback.  No state callbacks for the other two beacons.  Here is something interesting, which I tell you because of your interest in iBeacons:  even after I deleted the app from the phone and changed minor "0" to  minor "4" (no minor 0 exists in the code) my phone still reported back minor 0.

Comment: That last observation is interesting.  I am wondering if there is some caching bug in iOS that is storing a map of the BLE MAC address to iBeacon identifiers, such that when the iBeacon identifiers  change in the transmission, iOS still reports it to the app as the iBeacon identifiers it first saw based on the cached map.  You might test this theory by trying a **different hardware transmitter** with a different MAC address and start with minor "4".  I am wondering if in this case the reception gets "stuck" on minor 4.